# Is an Authentication service like Auth0, Firebase, IdentityServer4 responsible for sending back what the user has access to?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Firebase, Auth0, IdentityServer4 all provide an authentication layer for a front-app applications like Angular. I understand exactly what a user's identity is, but can never understand how Authorization (Roles, Claims, etc...) comes into play with the UI layer.

When a user logs in and a token (and other data) is sent back to the UI from one of the auth services, does this information typically contain the user's role or claims. For example, Admin, Employee, Manager, etc... Or does it not contain this information and instead the UI will use the user's unique identifer to look up the roles/claims in some other table in the database that the UI points to whether it is the same as the auth service database or not.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, no.  There is a clear separation of concerns between authentication and authorization.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Thanks for the great article, however, there is one thing I am still not understanding. So instead of passing a whole bunch of claims in a Json Web Token like "CanDeleteUser", "CanAddUser", "CanViewEmployee" etc... what is the alternative they are suggesting? Having the UI make a separate call to a server-side function called GetUserClaims that goes out to the database and returns the claims to be worked with?

Comment: Yes. That's the cleaner separation. This "authorization service" will then only return the permissions that are relevant for the caller.